# generate random numbers in methods

Tags: java, random, dice

I did the code, make a random number between 1 and 100 as task A), then how I understood if the first value if more than 50 generate second random number between 1 and 50 as said ( how I think) task B)

PLEASE can any one explain what the task C and D is, not understand how to do it at all ..(((pls help with advice or explanation task C and D.

Thanks....

TASK:

Write a program that generates random numbers:

a) +Write a method that returns a random integer in the range of 1 to 100.

b) Then add another method that takes a parameter specifying the top number – i.e. if you pass it 50 it returns a random number between 1 and 50.  Test your random method and make sure it works.

c) Write another method so that you pass it two values – the top and bottom of the range you want the highest value from – i.e. if you pass it 10 and 20 it returns a random number between 10 and 20.

d) Then write another method so that if repeatedly called it doesn’t return two numbers the same?  So once a random number has been generated and returned, the method doesn’t return that number again.  To do this you will have to store every number generated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ranGen {

    public Integer random (Integer integer){
        Random rand = new Random();;
        int min=0, max=100;
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

        System.out.println(randomNum);
        return randomNum;
        }


    public void random50 (Integer integer){


        Random rand = new Random();;
        int min=0, max=50;
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min +1) + min;

        System.out.println(randomNum);
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ranGen process = new ranGen();

        if(process.random(null) > 50){
            process.random50(null);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: C) Is nearly implemented in `random50(..)`you only need to pass the parameters `min` and `max`.

Comment: how about D? may be for you it clear, but I'm stuck for about 5 hours already..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of the homework, it seems, is to make you learn what method parameters are. The first step is to write a method that returns a random integer in the range of 1 to 100. So this method doesn't have any parameter. Its signature should be

```
public int generateRandomNumberBetween0And100()
```

The second step is to write a method which takes a parameter specifying the top number. Its signature should thus be:

```
public int generateRandomNumberBetween0And(int topValue)
```

The third step is to write a method taking two values as parameter: the bottom and the top value. Its signature should thus be:

```
public int generateRandomNumberBetween(int bottomValue, int topValue)
```

The last step is a bit more tricky. It asks you to remember the values a method has already generated, and to avoid generating them again. There is no parameter. Its signature should be

```
public int generateUniqueRandomNumber()
```

and its implementation should basically do the following:

```
1. generate random number
2. if random number is in the set of already generated numbers, go to 1
3. store the generated number in the set of already generated numbers
4. return the generated number.
```

Of course, the set of already generated numbers is empty at the beginning.

Note that you should use `int` rather than `Integer`. There's no reason to accept null as argument, and the methods should never return null. So the primitive `int` type should be preferred.

Also note that the methods should not *print* the generated number, but `return` it. So they should have `int` as their return type, and not `void`.

And classes, by convention, start with an upper-case letter and don't abbriviate words. So your class should be named `RandomGenerator`.

Comment: 1) what is topValue, is it the value from random number between 1 and 100?
2) topValue and bottomvalue is it like if between 1 and 100 generate 54 and the between 1 and 54 generate 20, so make a random number between 20 and 54?
3) I understand that no very clever but I not really get this: public int generateUniqueRandomNumber() (last section)

Comment: The top value is the maximum value that the method can generate. The bottom value is the minumum value that the method can generate. I didn't name the methods like this for nothing. It reads: generate random number between 0 and topValue. Or, for the third step: generate random number between bottomValue and topValue. Which is plain english.

Comment: The last step consists in avoiding repeating the already generated numbers. I don't know how it can be clearer than this. You ask the method to generate a number. This method generates one, and keeps retrying until the generated number is one that has not been generated before. As the homework says: you need to store all the already generated numbers to be able to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

c:

```
public Integer randomC(Integer min, Integer max) {
    //int min = 0, max = 0;
    ...
}
```

d:

```
public class ranGen {
    ArrayList<Integer> nums;
    ...

    public Integer randomD() {
        ...
        randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        while(nums.Exists(randomNum)) {
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        }
        nums.Add(randomNum);
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Note: arraylist and methods shown here for info purpose.